# How does find function in Map work in Scala?

Tags: scala, dictionary, find

I am new to Scala. This is the code that I have written.

```
object Main extends App {
    val mp: Map[String, String] = Map[String, String]("a"->"a", "b"->"b", "c"->"c", "d"->"d")
    val s: Option[(String, String)] = mp.find((a: String, b: String) => {
        if(a == "c" && b == "c") {
            true
        }
        else {
            false
        }
    })
    println(s)
}
```

I am getting the following error.

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : (String, String) => Boolean
required: ((String, String)) => Boolean
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change

```
mp.find((a: String, b: String) =>
```

to either

```
mp.find(((a: String, b: String)) =>
```

or

```
mp.find( case (a: String, b: String) =>
```

What you have coded is a function expecting two parameters, but you will only be passing in one, which is a `Pair` (also called `Tuple2`). The extra braces and the case keyword are ways of specifying that you are only passing in the one parameter, which is an instance of a Pair.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that find expects a function that takes a single argument, a `Tuple2` in this case and returns a `Boolean`: `((String, String)) => Boolean`. However, what you have there is a function that takes two args `a` and `b`, not a tuple (brackets matter): `(String, String) => Boolean`.

Here is one way to fix it. In this case I use pattern matching to extract arguments:

```
object Main extends App {
  val mp: Map[String, String] = Map[String, String]("a"->"a", "b"->"b", "c"->"c", "d"->"d")
  val s: Option[(String, String)] = mp.find{ case(a, b) => a == "c" && b == "c" }
  println(s)
}
```

alternatively you could also do:

```
val s: Option[(String, String)] = mp.find(t => t._1 == "c" && t._2 == "c")
```

Either would print:

```
Some((c,c))
```